# Legend position outside graph

Tags: r, graph, legend

I try to put the legend outside of the graph.
This is only half successful as you see.

Where do I have to change the numbers?

```
par(oma = c(0.1,1,0.1,1.5))
matplot(Profile2007, type = "l", lty = 1, col = colfunc(12), 
    ylab = "m asl", xlab="Distance along crossprofile [m]")
legend("topright", inset=c(-0.33,-0.0012), legend=1:12, xpd=T, 
   horiz=F, col=colfunc(12), lty =1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a reproducible example. So it's hard to tell what and where your problem is. What is Profile2007? What is colfunc? So, we cannot see that you're "half successful".

Anyway, the following works for me where I simulate some data:

```
Profile2007 <- matrix(rnorm(100*12), 100, 12)

par(oma = c(0.1,1,0.1,1.5))
matplot(Profile2007, type = "l", lty = 1, col = rainbow(12), 
        ylab = "m asl", xlab = "Distance along crossprofile [m]")
legend("topright", inset = c(-0.05,-0.1), legend = 1:12, xpd = TRUE, 
       horiz = TRUE, col = rainbow(12), lty = 1, bty = "n")
```

[image: Imgur]

Is that what you want?

**EDIT** Or this if you want the legend on the side:

```
Profile2007 <- matrix(rnorm(100*12), 100, 12)

par(mar =  c(5, 4, 4, 6) + 0.1)
matplot(Profile2007, type = "l", lty = 1, col = rainbow(12), 
        ylab = "m asl", xlab = "Distance along crossprofile [m]")
legend("right", inset = c(-0.17,0), legend = 1:12, xpd = TRUE, 
       horiz = FALSE, col = rainbow(12), lty = 1, bty = "n")
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: @user3216322 Sorry, but that "answer" doesn't provide much information. I can't run your code as I don't have `Profile07_6`. Please make sure that your code can run without errors from a *new* R session. By what I can tell, you can also avoid all the `abline` by using `grid()` instead.

Comment: @user3216322 I've edited my post. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer!
Sorry about that! 
Your example looks similar to what I want!

The colors are:
    colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "lightblue"))
    colfunc(12)

2007: 12 profile lines (cross profiles running through an accumulation lobe)
A sample:

> dput(head(Profile07_6))
>       structure(list(X12 = c(427.89, 427.89, 427.93, 427.96, 427.98, 
>       428), X11 = c(421.36, 421.34, 421.32, 421.28, 421.22, 421.18), 
>       X10 = c(415.81, 415.6, 415.44, 415.23, 415.03, 414.85), X9 = c(401.35, 
>       401.23, 401.11, 400.94, 400.78, 400.7), X8 = c(380.04, 379.85, 
>       379.64, 379.38, 379.15, 378.96), X7 = c(358.95, 359.13, 359.34, 
>       359.56, 359.78, 359.99), X6 = c(348.31, 348.52, 348.68, 348.83, 
>       348.96, 349.11)), .Names = c("X12", "X11", "X10", "X9", "X8", 
>       "X7", "X6"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

By the time, the graph looks like that

```
par(tcl=0.5)
matplot(Profile07_6, type = "l", lty = 1, col = colfunc(7), ylim=c(290,440), 
        ylab = "m asl", xlab="Distance along crossprofile [m]", main ="2007")
par(tcl=0.5)
minor.tick(ny=5, nx=2, tick.ratio=0.5)
abline(h=350, lty=3, col="grey33")
abline(h=400, lty=3, col="grey33")
abline(h=300, lty=3, col="grey33")
abline(h=290, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=310, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=320, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=330, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=340, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=360, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=370, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=380, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=390, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=410, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=420, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=430, lty=3, col="grey")
abline(h=440, lty=3, col="grey")
axis(4, at=c(290, 310, 320, 330, 340, 360, 370, 380, 390, 410, 420, 430, 440), 
     labels=c(290, 310, 320, 330, 340, 360, 370, 380, 390, 410, 420, 430, 440),
     col.axis="grey33", las=0, cex.axis=0.7, tck=0.01, col = "grey33", padj = -2.1)
```

Comment: Is this sample of help?

Comment: The legend shall be on the right side of the graph, so that it is easier to follow the colors...